# Maven doesn't run my Appium(selenium) tests

Tags: java, selenium, maven, appium, maven-surefire-plugin

My JDK is `1.8` version, Surefire is `2.22.2`, Maven is `3.6.3`. I am using junit and spring annotations.
When I try to run my tests with `mavn test` command, I get no errores, I get success build and no cases run.

> Running testCases.TestLogin
> Configuring TestNG with: org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.conf.TestNG652Configurator@7bb11784
> Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.808 sec

When I run the class using IntellIJ UI runner, the cases are run correctly. My class name starts with `Test*`. Here is my test code.

> ```
> package testCases;
>
> import appium.AppiumController;
> import org.junit.*;
> import org.springframework.context.annotation.Description;
> import screens.HomeScreen;
> import screens.LoginScreen;
>
> public class TestLogin extends AppiumController {
> protected static LoginScreen loginScreen;
> protected static HomeScreen homeScreen;
>
> @BeforeClass
> public static void setUp() throws Exception {
>     startAppium();
>     loginScreen = new LoginScreen(driver, wait);
>     homeScreen = new HomeScreen(driver, wait);
> }
>
> @After
> public void afterEach() {
>     loginScreen.appReset();
> }
>
> @Test
> @Description("Verify user can login with valid credentials")
> public void validLoginTest() throws Exception {
>     loginScreen.login("admin", "admin");
>     Assert.assertTrue("Home screen is not visible\n", homeScreen.isHomeScreenVisible());
> }
>
> @Test
> @Description("Verify user can not login with invalid credentials")
> public void invalidLoginTest() throws Exception {
>     loginScreen.login("admin1", "admin1");
>     Assert.assertFalse("Home screen is visible\n", homeScreen.isHomeScreenVisible());
> }
>
> @AfterClass
> public static void tearDown() throws Exception {
>     stopAppium();
> }
> ```

What is the problem and how can I run the test cases using command line?

Comment: Follow Naming conventions and name tests like `*Test.java` .. apart from that classes should start with an uppercase character ... The error output does not look like that .. Please show a full example of your test class. Where have you located your class etc. and which Maven version, JDK version, maven-surefire-plugin versions etc. are you using ?...

Comment: @khmarbaise Updated the questions accroding to your comment. I would like to notice that I am not getting any errors. Thanks.

Comment: First post the full class not excerpts...second do you use TestNG or JUnit 4.X or JUnit Jupiter ? Also the full pom file will help...

Comment: I am using JUnit 4.12

Comment: Your statement contradicts what the error message is telling: `Configuring TestNG with: org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.conf.TestNG652Configu`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be having both TestNg and Junit dependencies in the POM.xml

As per documentation of maven-surefire-plugin plugin for TestNg .You may want to run two providers, e.g. surefire-junit47 and surefire-testng, and avoid running JUnit tests within surefire-testng provider by setting property junit=false.

**Documentation** [Ref](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/testng.html) - Section **'Running TestNG and JUnit Tests'**

```
 <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
    <configuration>
      
      <properties>
        <property>
          <name>junit</name>
          <value>false</value>
        </property>
      </properties>
      <threadCount>1</threadCount>
     
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
        <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
        <artifactId>surefire-testng</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: Thank you soooo much! I needed to use surefire-junit47 plugin!